# htaccess redirect to another site on certain file extensions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect to another site (storage), if client requests *.pdf or *.cdr files.

The problem is that, with the below htaccess, cdr downloading works, but not pdf.
If a change the rule order (cdr first, pdf second), then the pdf works, but not the cdr.

I've tried `[OR]`, other regex to catch both extensions in one pattern. This is the only one that works (half-works).
The files (pdf or cdr) to which the redirection points *exist* (I checked through FTP).

I currently have in the root .htaccess:

```
#<snip>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

# catch site.ro/some_file.pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://docs.site.com/$1 [L,R]

# catch site.ro/some_file.cdr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+cdr)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://docs.site.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d               # If not an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f               # If not an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|cdr)$ [NC]      # If filename ends with .pdf or .cdr
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://docs.site.com/$1 [L,R]  # Redirect the user to the other site

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]       # Redirect all other requests to index.php
```

Hope this helps you